# Image not being displayed in Windows 8.1 Store application

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm

I have a Windows 8.1 Store application and in one of the views I need to display an image. I've done this a million times in WPF desktop application, so it should be easy to do and yet my image is not displayed. I get this image from the repository as a byte array. I checked and I have all the bytes in my ViewModel at the time my view is displayed. Yet, I don't see it. This is the first time I actually try to display an image in a Windows 8.1 Store application, so I wonder if things are done differently.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5" Margin="2">
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageBuffer}" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding CompanyName}"
           Width="280" Height="190" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

The code behind contains an "ImageBuffer" public property that, like I said, is properly initialized with all the bytes of the image.

```
private byte[] _imageBuffer;
public byte[] ImageBuffer
{
   get { return _imageBuffer; }
   set { Set(() => ImageBuffer, ref _imageBuffer, value); }
}
```

I use MVVM Light Toolkit for my project.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Eddie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no automatic type conversion from `byte[]` to `ImageSource` in WinRT (as it is in WPF). You should have seen an error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio like

> Error: Converter failed to convert value of type
>   'Windows.Foundation.IReferenceArray`1' to type 'ImageSource'; ...

So you should use a Binding Converter like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
...

public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        var buffer = value as byte[];

        if (buffer != null)
        {
            using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                stream.AsStreamForWrite().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                stream.Seek(0);
                bitmap.SetSource(stream);
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it in the `Image.Source` Binding like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
...
<Image Source="{Binding ImageBuffer, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" ... />
```

Comment: Thank you, Clemens. That really worked. I saw the error in the Output window. I've learned to look at it too when something does not work as expected.

Comment: One other comment for people trying Clemens' solution, the "AsStreamForWrite" is an extension method that is available only if you add the System.IO namespace. That was not immediately clear for me and since I don't have ReSharper in my Visual Studio 2015, I had to dig around a little bit to find out where is that method coming from. Anyway, an excellent solution. Thanks again Clemens.